# How can i set when to run Typescript decorators

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, aop, interceptor

When I define a parameterized decorator for the method, the decorator starts running before the method runs.

I want the decorator to run after the method is called.

```
 function fooDecorator(value: boolean) {
  console.log('fooDecorator init');
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
  };
}

class Foo{


  @fooDecorator(true)
  foo(){

  }

}

app.listen(5000, () => console.log("server started"));




// Output 
fooDecoratorinit
server started
```

Comment: Of course it does, it has to run to decorate the method. See [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html).

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript method decorators run during class initialization, so they can decorate the method; see the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html). If you want a decorator to do something when the method is *called*, you have the decorator wrap the method in another function that does the thing you want it to do:

```
function fooDecorator(flag: boolean) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string; descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        const original = target[propertyKey];
        return {
            ...descriptor,
            value(...args: any[]) {
                console.log("Inserted behavior, flag = " + flag);
                return original.apply(this, args);
            }
        }
    };
}

class Foo{
    @fooDecorator(true)
    foo(){
        console.log("Original foo");
    }
}

const f = new Foo();
f.foo();
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAiBTCcBOBDKXACmABs8BzALkQCNVSM8wBKRAbwChEfEcMoIHElCRYCRESh4cFATWYBPADSIADjjhqMOKIoDSGRTQDOUHDDAUA3IgAmGExAtrCOGgAVN23YsxOXNzYuXlDEbDAzRFwYCks8UkQAXkRpWQEAbQ0tHT1DRQBda24wnn5BYQ4S0tCAOnqHAJhXXGVqmp4ANwSQDCJ62pkKEwUwRQyC4PaO0IiTOEZa0jgKIgAiAElI3Iw7OgwACzxO+BxVMkpkxDXEAGpkcgoWYpma8qEkGLiwBMG1NVIiikBxgJlUQxMz2mNQAvtCeHDQjDinDOBByCYTIgAGKoEK8AACKHQWFwBGI5l6LHaxKILHxpTmCwwSxW6wA8hZvglkKg1lCkZxUXMoMgrmAMAB3HGoOnFYC1WnPIA)

Output:

```
Inserted behavior, flag = true
Original foo
```